# How to fix nil error on IBOutlet configuration and UI not showing when View Controller is called?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I've been getting an error when I'm trying to configuring my IBOutlets programmatically. Whenever I tried to setup my UI I've been getting this error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

But when I commented the code (the `setupKategori()` function), my UI became transparent like this (you can see that only the Nav Bar is visible, where all of the items in the XIB file should've been visible):

[image]

Here's my code :

**Setup UI function**

```
func setupKategori() { // the function that throws the error whenever I call it in viewDidLoad()
        kategoriLabel.font = .boldTitilliumWeb(ofSize: 18)
        kategoriLabel.textColor = .init(hex: "#333333")
        kategoriLabel.sizeToFit()

        kategoriDetailLabel.font = .boldTitilliumWeb(ofSize: 18)
        kategoriDetailLabel.textColor = .init(hex: "#222222")
        kategoriDetailLabel.sizeToFit()

        showKategoriButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showKategoriAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

EDIT : **Calling the View Controller**

```
func routeToFilter() {
    //Analytics.logEvent("pw_list_filter", parameters: nil)
    let destinationVC = FilterPWVC()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationVC)
    present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

For just some information, I've already connected the IBOutlets from the XIB file. And I'm really new to iOS programming so I still have limited knowledge about it. If you need any more info feel free to ask and I will provide it to you. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the code where you instantiate this view controller?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler done

Comment: Thanks. You say you're using a xib file – what is the name of the file? Is it `FilterPWVC.xib`, or something else? If it doesn't match your view controller's class name exactly, then you need to specify the nib name when initializing the view controller by using `FilterPWVC(nibName:bundle:)` (see the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init)).

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler my xib file named `FilterPWView.xib` I believe. Thank you for you help! I will look it up :)

Comment: No prob! Please edit your question to include the name of your xib file too, so that that info is not buried in the comments here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to instantiate your view controller using the `init()` method (which in turn calls `init(nibName:bundle:)` with nil parameters), then if you are expecting your view controller to be loaded from a xib file, your xib file's filename must be the same as your view controller's class name.

So, in your case, it should be: "FilterPWVC.xib", not "FilterPWView.xib".

OR, instead of renaming the xib and using `init()`, you could also specify the nib name by using `init(nibName:bundle:)` directly, like so:

```
// I'm assuming the xib is in the main bundle, so I've passed `nil` 
// in for the bundle here
let destinationVC = FilterPWVC(nibName: "FilterPWView", bundle: nil)
```